# What's the best separation you can get on set sums?

Tags: analysis

Given a set $S = \{ a_1 < a_2 < \ldots < a_n \}$ of real numbers, we want to maximize the separation between any sum of n elements with replacement and the total of the set.

That is, let $C = \{ (c_1, ... c_n) | 0 \leq c_i \leq n, \sum c_i = n \} / \{ (1,1,\ldots ,1) \}$,
and define the "set-sum-separation" of S to be $\min_C |(\sum c_i a_i - \sum a_i)| / n(a_n - a_1)$.

How do we pick $S$ to maximize this separation, and how does the maximum separation behave as a function of n?

For $n=2$, our set $S = \{a,b\}$, our set sum is $a+b$, and possible sums are $\{2a, a+b, 2b \}$, with the central term only coming from selecting one $a$ and one $b$.  So the set-sum-separation is |(2a - (a+b))| / 2(b-a) = |(2b - (a+b))| / 2(b-a) = 1/2. And this is independent of S.

For $n=3$, our set $S = \{a,b,c\}$, our set sum is $a+b+c$, and possible sums are $\{3a < 2a+b < a+2b, 2a+c < a+b+c < a+2c, 2b+c < b+2c < 3c \} \cup \{3b\}$, with $a+2b < 3b < 2b+c$ but incomparable with $\{ 2a+c, a+b+c, a+2c \}$ without additional information.
The difference between the central term $a+b+c$ and the nearest other term is $\min \{b-a, c-b, |c+a-2b|\}$, and the set-sum-separation is $\min \{b-a, c-b, |c+a-2b|\} / 3(c-a)$.  If we want to maximize this, we can't have $b$ being the average of $a$ and $c$ as that would make the last term 0.  So suppose WLOG that $b$ is closer to $a$.  Then we can drop the $c-b$ term, and to maximize, we want $b-a = c+a - 2b$, or $b = (c+2a)/3$. So the maximizing set $S$ looks like $\{0,1,3\}$ up to affine transformation, and the set-sum-separation is $1/9$.

Comment: This problem is e.g. related to Golomb rulers and arithmetic-sequence-free sets.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the optimal set for $n=4$ is $S = \{0,1,3,7\}$ up to affine transformation -- the only way to get 11 with four elements of the set is $0+1+3+7$, the next nearest sums are 10 and 12, so the sum-set-separation is $1 / 4*7 = 1/28$.